# How to process a large list in Scala?

Tags: python, file, scala, jvm, out-of-memory

I used to handle stats stuff in Python. For example, a large file contains tens of millions of ids:

```
$ cat report_ids | head
3788065
7950319
140494477
182851142
120757318
160033281
78087029
42591118
104363873
212143796
...
```

In IPython, the following lines works well always.

```
In [1]: lines = [line.strip() for  line in open('./report_ids').readlines()]

In [2]: from collections import Counter

In [3]: d = Counter(lines)

In [4]: d[lines[0]]
Out[4]: 9
```

When I try the same in Scala, an out of memory errors occurs.

```
val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("./report_ids").getLines.toList
lines: List[String] = List(3788065, 7950319, 140494477, 182851142, 120757318, 160033281, 78087029, 42591118, 104363873, 212143796, 175644298, 112703123, 213308679, 109649718, 11947300, 214660563, 83402867, 162877289, 83030111, 78231639, 45129180, 11635655, 34778452, 46604760, 142519099, 213261965, 137812002, 167057636, 119258917, 212722777, 177979907, 13754217, 156769524, 40682536, 202195379, 91879046, 22766751, 6656279, 11972540, 76929862, 91616020, 110579570, 143849021, 27239477, 65146692, 142968764, 153891284, 182405787, 153038108, 50714639, 113386401, 96657813, 75908413, 32215626, 175000692, 154337083, 113754207, 165109267, 3788065, 42285876, 171004203, 109802388, 92956305, 46690091, 103638776, 15141632, 110579570, 120984867, 183167775, 86841540, 60465849, 27239477, 91760184, 213464...

scala> val g = lines.groupBy(e => e).mapValues(x => x.length)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.updated0(HashMap.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.updated0(HashMap.scala:326)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap.$plus(HashMap.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap.$plus(HashMap.scala:36)
    at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.mutable.MapBuilder.$plus$eq(MapBuilder.scala:24)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$groupBy$3.apply(TraversableLike.scala:334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$groupBy$3.apply(TraversableLike.scala:333)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.groupBy(TraversableLike.scala:333)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.groupBy(Traversable.scala:105)
    at .<init>(<console>:8)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:760)
```

Then I tried the **lazy** method in Scala, its still not working.

```
scala> lazy val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("./report_ids").getLines.toList
lines: List[String] = <lazy>

scala> val g = lines.groupBy(e => e).mapValues(x => x.length)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:349)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource$BufferedLineIterator.hasNext(BufferedSource.scala:67)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:176)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:257)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toList(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at .lines$lzycompute(<console>:7)
    at .lines(<console>:7)
    at .<init>(<console>:8)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:760)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:805)
```

So how can I finished the group by work in Scala as the way I did in Python? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think are doing something rather different in Python and Scala. Let's look at that first line:

```
lines = [line.strip() for  line in open('./report_ids').readlines()]
```

It looks to me that you are working with an iterable here (in Scala terms), not a real list. I might be wrong -- I don't work with Python often enough to remember -- but let's assume you are and see how you can get the same thing in Scala. You had this:

```
val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("./report_ids").getLines.toList
```

Now, Scala doesn't have a file iterable in the standard library, though I think Scala I/O comes with one. Here, you can do this to get an iterator (not the same thing):

```
val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("./report_ids").getLines
```

Just don't turn it into a `List`. :) Now, since this is an iterator, not an iterable, it would fail once you used it twice. So let's write it like this instead:

```
def lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("./report_ids").getLines
```

Now you can use "lines" multiple times. Sadly, you'll leak file descriptors -- for more serious I/O handling, look at a more serious I/O library such as Scalaz Stream or Scala I/O. Or use the loan pattern.

Next, you replace the `Counter` code with this:

```
val g = lines.groupBy(e => e).mapValues(x => x.length)
```

That's going to be memory intensive. Something like this should be much better:

```
val g = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.empty[String, Int] withDefaultValue 0
for (line <- lines) g(line) += 1
```

Since `lines` is an `Iterator`, you won't be able to do `lines(0)`. For the first line, you could just do `lines.next`, or you can do `lines.toStream(0)` to be access an index without reading the whole file into memory.